# What's the importance of the Offset variable in this algorithm?

Tags: c#, variables, crc

What's the meaning of this variable named Offset in this algorithm ?
It's declared in the second calcCrc16 parameter.
For me it's useless bcause it's aways zero and it's used in a sum.

this algorithm generates a crc-16. I'm trying to understand this algorithm bcause a have to create a algorithm that verify crc-16, and i want to use this code as base.

```
public sealed class CRC
{
    private readonly int _polynom;

    public static readonly CRC Default = new CRC(0xA001);

    public CRC(int polynom)
    {
        _polynom = polynom;
    }

    public int CalcCrc16(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return CalcCrc16(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, _polynom, 0);
    }

    public static int CalcCrc16(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bufLen, int polynom, int preset)
    {
        preset &= 0xFFFF;
        polynom &= 0xFFFF;

        var crc = preset;
        for (var i = 0; i < (bufLen + 2); i++)
        {
            var data = buffer[(i + offset) % buffer.Length] & 0xFF;
            crc ^= data;
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ polynom;
                }
                else
                {
                    crc = crc >> 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return crc & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the starting position in the raw data array. If you don't want the header to take part in the CRC calculation then you'd set this to a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple example, using a small 4 byte message (in a 6 byte buffer):

```
using System;
namespace crc16
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ushort Crc16(byte[] bfr, int bfrlen)
        {
            ushort crc = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bfrlen; i++)
            {
                crc ^= bfr[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    // assumes twos complement math
                    crc = (ushort)((crc >> 1)^((0 - (crc&1)) & 0xa001));
            }
            return crc;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ushort crc;
            byte[] data = new byte[6] {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00};
            crc = Crc16(data, 4);           // generate crc
            data[4] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);   // append crc (lsb first)
            data[5] = (byte)(crc >> 8);
            crc = Crc16(data, 6);           // verify crc;
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X4}", crc);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting 0 as result ?

Comment: The first call returns the CRC for the 4 byte message and the second call returns 0.

Comment: @Levi - you might want to consider deleting your other questions if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the signature of a `public` method, suitable whenever you want to calculate a CRC, but not on your entire buffer.

Sure, most of the time you may just use the simple version of the method, and in that case the parameter is always zero, but typically hashing and CRC implementations are built with an API like this, allowing you to calculate your CRC in chunks if you'd like.

Comment: thank you, can i have one more question ? I'm trying to use this same algorithm to make the receiver side of a wireless comunication, so i have to verify the crc-16, do you have any suggestion how can i adapt this code for this function ?

Comment: @Levi - assuming the CRC16 is appended to the message, then use buflen+2 and verify that the returned CRC is 0x0000.

Comment: @rcgldr I tried use what you said, I used buflen + 2, but I still can't get 0x0000 as answer. I've edited the example algorithm for you to see the cange.